# Pass an array of user_params to update in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to bulk update users, and in so, passing an array of user information to user_params. I know(/believe) this is the issue, but I don't understand how to solve it, it keeps giving me the error of 'ArgumentError in UsersController#update_all - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)'

I believe the question I'm asking is, how do I optionally pass an array to user_params for a bulk update, but can also send it a single user's information. Any information is appreciated to understand where I'm missing what is happening.

Thanks!

users_controller.rb

```
 def update_all
 params["user"].keys.each do |id|
      @user = User.find(id.to_i)
      @user.update_attributes(user_params(id))
    end
    redirect_to(users_path)
  end

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_id, :approved)
end
```

Form

```
<h1>Editing users</h1>

<%= form_for :user, :url => update_all_path, :html => { :method => :put } do %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>E-Mail</th>
    </tr>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <%= fields_for "user[]", user do |user_fields| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user_fields.text_field :first_name %></td>
      <td><%= user_fields.text_field :last_name %></td>
      <td><%= user_fields.email_field :email %></td>
      <td><%= user_fields.check_box :approved %></td>

    </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </table>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `user_params` with an argument, but that method (`def user_params`) takes no argument.

Since you've set up your form to send multiple users, `params[:user]` look like this:

```
{
  "1"=>{"first_name"=>"K", "last_name"=>"P", "email"=>"k@", "approved"=>"1"},
  "2"=>{"first_name"=>"A", "last_name"=>"Q", "email"=>"a@", "approved"=>"0"}
}
```

So the simplest thing to do is run `each` on that whole Hash instead of on `.keys`:

```
params["user"].each do |id, attributes|
  User.find(id).update_attributes(attributes)
end
```

That avoids your strong parameter requirements, though, but you're going to need to do a little more work in there to handle the whole hash. After requiring `:user`, you need to `permit` fields on each value in that hash:

```
def bulk_user_params
  users = params.require(:user).permit!
  users.each do |id, attributes|
    users[id] = attributes.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :approved)
  end
end
```

The `permit!` allows any keys in `params[:user]`, which you need because those keys are `1`, `2`, etc. Then the looped `permit` and assignment filters the attribute hashes down to what you expect.

Once the new, safe hash is constructed, use it in `update_all` instead of the basic `user_params`:

```
bulk_user_params.each do |id, attributes|
  User.find(id).update_attributes(attributes)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@user.update_attributes(user_params(id))
```

should be

```
@user.update_attributes(user_params)
```